# What is the cause of this strange function declaration in GO?

Tags: go, syntax

In most of the function declarations I've seen in Go, the format is Name, Arguments, Output. Such as the following:

```
func add(a, b int) int {
  return a + b
}
```

But in this example, the pointer is given in the beginning of the declaration, instead of in the argument section right after the name. My question is: what is the cause is this format? Are pointers written differently when they're arguments?

```
func (p *Page) save() error {
  filename := p.Title + ".txt"
  return ioutil.WriteFile(filename, p.Body, 0600)
}
```

Comment: That's a method.

Comment: this is how you define a method on a type in go and it’s a reference type as opposed to without the asterisk is a value type

Comment: and the technical term in go is a `receiver`

Comment: Reference: https://tour.golang.org/methods/1

Comment: Thanks! If you write it as an answer then I'll accept it.

Comment: There's nothing strange about that function declaration at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in `go` there are no classes in the way you usually see them .. instead we use the syntax in question do declare methods on types, the argument in front is called a`receiver` and if we use a `pointer receiver` we get `reference` type semantics otherwise you get `value` type semantics. check out the `go` tour it is awesome.